# how do i make a 3d character move in unity with WASD?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I am new to Unity, and I want to make a 3d character movement. Please help me. I have tried tutorials, but they don't work.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials and controllers around. “Doesn’t work” gives no idea of what. Rest assured it is something you are missing in the tutorials you have watched.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of ways to make a player move in 3D, and there are just as many tutorials that explain it.  If you need a place to start, see the [character controller component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html).
If you have a 3d model of the character, just add this component and it will start moving right away.
the gameobject does not have to have rigidbody or collider components, because it takes care of the whole character controller.

**If I gave you a hand to get started, you can mark my answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), and vote it positively :)**

Answer (score -1):

You first have to choose what kind of movement you want to accomplish *i.e: 1st person, 3rd person etc*. And saying that YouTube tutorials don't work definitely means you are missing something. Here are some good tutorials for different 3d movement. Please follow them thoroughly.

**1st Person:**

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAC8U9-dTZU

**3rd Person:**

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HpC--2iowE

You can find a ton more movement systems on Google.

Your movement depends on your usage. You have to use a different approach if you want it to be Character Controller based than Rigidbody based. So learn the basics, and then experiment on your own until you are happy with it.